# Reading CSV file and generating Dictionaries

Tags: csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file looks like

Hit39,  Hit24,  Hit9

Hit8,   Hit39,  Hit21

Hit46,  Hit47,  Hit20

Hit24,  Hit 53, Hit46

I want to read file and create a dictionary based on the first come first serve first basis

like Hit39 : 1, Hit 24:2 and so on ...

but notice Hit39 appeared on column 2 and row2 . So if the reader reads it then it should not append it to dictionary it will move on with the new number.

Once a row number is visited it shouldn't include numbers after that if appeared.

Comment: What is the expected output from the input?

Comment: Also, the example is not enough to understand what you want. Why is the second Hit39 excluded? Because it was encountered before, or because it succedes Hit8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Python** - Best guess until the OP is clarified - treat the file as though it was one huge list and assign an incrementing variable to unique occurences of value.

```
import csv
from itertools import count

mydict = {}
counter = count(1)
with open('infile.csv') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True):
        for col in row:
            mydict[col] = mydict.get(col, next(counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is a popular language that has dictionaries, you *must* be using Python. At least I assume.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(file("filename.csv"))
d = dict((line[0], 1+lineno) for lineno, line in enumerate(reader))

print d
```